# Highcharts spider chart padding issue

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a spider chart with a plot band that runs up against the outer edge of the circular border.  Unfortunately, no matter what I try (yAxis max, yAxis maxPadding, plotBand thickness....) (tested in Firefox and Chrome), it ends up with some white space in between the yAxis max and the edge of the chart. I'm creating a bullseye pattern in my actual application, which looks fine except for the whitespace.

**edit**: the problem is not that I cannot fill in this whitespace (I can if I just increase the plotBand end to beyond the yAxis.max.  The problem is that this area exists at all--I also want the last point to go up to the edge of the chart, so the inner plot bands are not shrunken to scale.

In this example, there's also whitespace in the middle of the circle--that's ok.
http://jsfiddle.net/XEte8/

html:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            polar:true
        },
        yAxis: {        
            plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
                color: '#FCFFC5',
                from: 0,
                to: 250,
            }],
            max:250,
            endOnTick:true,
            maxPadding:0,
            minPadding:0,
            startOnTick:true,
            tickmarkPlacement:"on"
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `endOnTick` option is true, `max` will sometimes be rounded up. I updated your fiddle with `endOnTick:false`:
http://jsfiddle.net/XEte8/1/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is configure [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval)

javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        polar:true,
        marginTop: 10
    },
    yAxis: {        
        plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: 100,
            to: 250,
        }],
        max:250,
        tickInterval: 50,       
        startOnTick:true,
        tickmarkPlacement:"on"
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ng3s5/

Comment: I'm fairly sure this would have worked too--if I could split the answer credit I would.  Upvoted instead.